# Yii2 Как использовать данные связанной модели для фильтрации

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

У меня есть модель Candidates и связанная модель Additional_Status - с таким полями - candidate_id(id кандидата), New(Новый кандидат), Considered, Today(не старше трех дней), Offer, Selected, Blacklist. Моя модель Additional_Status выглядит следующим образом:

```html
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use crm\entities\candidate\Candidate;
use Yii;


/**
 * This is the model class for table "additional_status".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $candidate_id
 * @property int $new
 * @property int $considered
 * @property int $today
 * @property int $offer
 * @property int $selected
 * @property int $blacklisted
 *
 * @property Candidates $candidate
 */
class AdditionalStatus extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'additional_status';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['candidate_id'], 'required'],
            [['new', 'considered', 'today', 'offer', 'selected', 'blacklisted'], 'integer'],
            [['candidate_id'], 'string', 'max' => 36],
            [['candidate_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => candidate::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['candidate_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'candidate_id' => 'Candidate ID',
            'new' => 'New',
            'considered' => 'Considered',
            'today' => 'Today',
            'offer' => 'Offer',
            'selected' => 'Selected',
            'blacklisted' => 'Blacklisted',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCandidate()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(candidate::className(), ['id' => 'candidate_id']);
    }

    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        return parent::beforeSave($insert); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }
}
```

Я хочу в отдельном списке выводить кандидатов, к примеру со статусом new и today а также blacklist. У меня есть код который выводит кандидатов (но данные берутся из поля status модели Candidate).

```html
    public function actionIndex($status='', $id=0, $search='')
    {
        $condition = ($status && is_numeric($status))?['current_status'=>$status]:[];
        $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
            'allModels'     => $this->service->getAll($condition, trim($search)),
            'pagination'    => ['pageSize'  => 0,],
        ]);

        $model =  $this->findModel($id);

        return $this->render('index',[
            'dataProvider'  => $dataProvider,
            'id'            => $id,
            'model'         => $model
        ]);
    }
```

Как мне его необходимо изменить что бы можно было работать со статусами из связанной таблицы Additional_status - для фильтрации кандидатов по статусам из этой таблицы? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно добавить релейшен в модель Candidate и связать ее с модлью статусов

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->hasOne(AdditionalStatus::className(), ['candidate_id' => 'id']);
}
```